# how to get onchange value after select navigation menu in magento?

Tags: magento

hi all how to get onchange value after select navigation menu in magento?
i trying to following code in topmenu.phtmlbut it's not working proper showing page is not found
But it's not working properly. What do i do?

Comment: here is topmenu.phtml <select id="nav" class="nav"  onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </select>

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
<select id="nav" class="nav" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
```

Comment: what are the value in your select options

Comment: select option value get name

Comment: i trying to also this code <select class="browser_box" name="browser" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"> <option>Please select a category...</option> <?php $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation(); $store_cats = $obj->getStoreCategories(); $current_cat = $obj->getCurrentCategory(); $current_cat = (is_object($current_cat) ? $current_cat->getName() : ''); foreach ($store_cats as $cat) { echo '<option value="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</option>"; }?> </select> but value not get

Comment: is it complete url or just page name? can you paste the option value (html rendered code)

Comment: pankaj, I have modified my answer you can try this one

Comment: i trying to that but it's not proper working display like this url localhost/littletreasures/Men%27s%20Wear

Comment: something work but not get name in value 'localhost/littletreasures/Men%27s%20Wear' and i want like this 'http://localhost/littletreasures/men-s-wear.html'

Comment: check your option values are proper in html of option

Comment: this is topmenu.php $html .= '<option ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
. $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
if ($child->hasChildren()) {
if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
$html .= '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
}
$html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . '">';
$html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass);
$html .= '</ul>';
if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
$html .= '</div>';
}
}
$html .= '</option>';

Comment: your php code has span and div, how can be these tags are part of option value in select?

Comment: i removed span and but also not kindly tell me what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Update `Topmenu.php` code with below code.

Remove this:

```
$html .= '<option ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>'; 
$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>'; 

if ($child->hasChildren()) { 
    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) { 
        $html .= '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">'; 
    } 
    $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . '">'; 
    $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass); 
    $html .= '</ul>'; 
    if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) { 
        $html .= '</div>'; 
    } 
} 
$html .= '</option>';
```

Add below code:

```
$html .= '<option value="' . $child->getUrl() . '" '>'. $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</option>'; 
if ($child->hasChildren()) { 
    $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass);
}
```

And update select `onchange` code with below code:

```
onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value"
```

Comment: sorry get error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\littletreasures\app\code\local\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Topmenu.php on line 125